# Issue with click function highcharts-ng and Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, highcharts, highcharts-ng

I set up a factory provider for my graph. The graph is built from highcharts and highcharts-ng which is an angularjs highcharts directive.

Within my controller named SentimentChartController I then created a click function on my graph nodes as follows:

```
$scope.AveSentimentChartConfigMain.options.plotOptions.series.point.events.click = function () {
      var containerDiv = document.createElement('div');
      containerDiv.setAttribute('id', 'postListPopUpContainer');
      containerDiv.setAttribute('ng-controller', 'SentimentChartController');
      var contentDiv = document.createElement('div');
      contentDiv.setAttribute('id', 'postListPopUp');
      contentDiv.innerHTML = '<img onclick="closeDrillDown()" src="images/closePostListPopUp.svg" title="Click to close" class="closeIcon" width="18" height="18"><h2>' +
      this.category + ' ' + this.series.name + '</h2>' +
      '<p class="drillDownInfo"><strong>' + this.y + '%</strong> of posts where we can determine a sentiment are ' + this.category + '</p>';
      document.body.appendChild(containerDiv);
      containerDiv.appendChild(contentDiv);
    };
```

The html generated once you click on a graph node is as follows:

```
<div id="postListPopUpContainer" ng-controller="SentimentChartController">
  <div id="postListPopUp">
    <img src="images/closePostListPopUp.svg" title="Click to close" class="closeIcon" width="18" height="18" onclick="closeDrillDown()">
    <h2>Positive Sentiment</h2>
    <p class="drillDownInfo"><strong>26%</strong> of posts where we can determine a sentiment are Positive</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

In my SentimentChartController I also declared the following function:

```
$scope.closeDrillDown = function() {
      alert('function called');
};
```

This function should fire onclick of the following img element which is created during my click function defined above

```
<img onclick="closeDrillDown()" src="images/closePostListPopUp.svg" title="Click to close" class="closeIcon" width="18" height="18">
```

However I get a "Uncaught ReferenceError: closeDrillDown is not defined" error.

Why is this happening even though I set up ng-controller="SentimentChartController" in my container div

Answer (score 0):

For scoped functions you should use ng-click attribute instead onclick, you received the error because your functions is defined in your scope and not as a global javascript function, other thing is, select dom in controller is not a good practice, try use angular.element to make this dom selections in a separated directive

Comment: Thanks for the help. I just replaced onclick with ng-click and don't receive the Uncaught reference error but now nothing happens when I click on my element.

It still doesn't look like my function is getting fired. Any idea why?

Comment: As I see, your function select nothing in document.getElementById, you need to pass the Id of element that you want to set style document.getElementById('myElement').style.display='none'; if you put one alert in your function you will see if the functions is called

Comment: Sorry forgot to change that in my question:

The function should now provide an alert('function called') but this is not happening. Using chrome dev tools I have realized that the function never get triggered but I don't know why

Comment: The unique problem that I already see you solved, try check if controller is correct defined and use <a> link element with your icon inside to trigger the ng-click <a href ng-click="closeDrillDown()"><img...

Comment: Also doesn't work... In fact no angular directives work in my highcharts click function. I will have to relook this whole thing

Comment: Seems a highcharts bug, check this link, maybe make senses for your context problem http://gotoanswer.stanford.edu/?q=Cannot+update+Highcharts+series+in+click+event+with+highcharts-ng